# Why the below flex code doesn't show output?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, flex-lexer

```
digit  [0-9]
letter [A-Za-z]
%{
int count;
%}
%%
     /* match identifier */
{letter}({letter}|{digit})*  count++;
%%
int main(void) {
yylex();
printf("number of identifiers = %d\n", count);
return 0;
}
```

Doesn't work **printf statement**.
can you explain what should i include in this code.

Comment: does the program correctly terminate?

Comment: no doesn't terminate.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] sections soon, and more urgently about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You've provided code, which is good.  You've not described the input data nor how you are providing the data to the program.  Your explanation "Doesn't work printf statement" isn't helpful.  You should be more explicit about what you observe.  Also, please note that the [tag:flex] is not the same as [tag:flex-lexer] — and the latter is the correct one to use for the Flex lexical analyzer (or lexer).  The other tag is for the Adobe web-language Flex.

Comment: tq @Jonathan Leffler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an error with `yywrap` -- just add `%option noyywrap`:

```
digit  [0-9]
letter [A-Za-z]
%{
    int count;
%}

%option noyywrap

%%
     /* match identifier */
{letter}({letter}|{digit})*  count++;
%%

int main(void) {
    yylex();
    printf("number of identifiers = %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Then compile:

```
flex f.l
gcc lex.yy.c
```

Run and **don't forget to send EOF at the end (with Ctrl-D)**:

```
./a.out
a a a

number of identifiers = 3
```